# How to read variables from a matlab code into workspace?

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab in the current directory 'Run_Code.m'
I have written another matlab code which should load all the variables in 'Run_Code.m' into the matlab workspace. I used the following code :

```
load('Run_Code'.m)
```

But I get the following error :

```
Error using load
Unable to read file 'Run_Code.m'. No such file or directory.
```

This is in spite of the code being in the current directory

Comment: ...why would you want to `load` an M-file?!

Comment: I want to use the variable in that M-file into my other file

Comment: Why don't you *run* it then?

Comment: I want to use those variable without running that M-file. Is that possible? Im making a GUI in which i dont want the user to first run that file and then use the variables

Comment: you can have the GUI run that file during startup

Comment: Can you show us a bit of the contents of both files?

Comment: Put the variable in your handles for the GUI

Comment: Read this one: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152715-how-to-share-multiple-variables-in-different-m-files?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 0):

*.m files do not contain variables. These files contain code. It is *.mat files that contain variables.
To load a *.mat file the command is load('MyVariables.mat');